# Sending Emails to right users using variables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to send emails to the appropriate users when a button is clicked. The email addresses are stored in my database where I have set them to a variable, so it can dynamically send to the right users when button is clicked. I have used the following code

```
$mailquery = "SELECT email FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_bides ON tbl_users.email = tbl_bides.bidder_id";
while ($mailentry = mysql_fetch_array($mailquery)) {
$mail = $mailentry['email'];
$to = $mail;
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Right User!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" ."CC:somebodyelse@example.com";
mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
}
```

This doesn't work.
Please help!!

Comment: Please update your code. `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for over 2 years now. They tend to leave you wide open to MySQL injection. It's strongly adviced to use [MySQLi()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in combination with Prepared Statements. Aside from that: How does it not work? Explain your problem in more detail so we have a general idea about what's going on.

Comment: *"so it can dynamically send to the right users when button is clicked"* - you're going to need to elaborate on that. I've posted an answer below and outlined what you're not doing. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to show us more code and how exactly that dynamic stuff is happening. You may need to use a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query isn't being executed.

```
$mailquery = "SELECT email...
```

It needs to contain `mysql_query()`.

```
$mailquery = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_bides ON tbl_users.email = tbl_bides.bidder_id");
```

Or, if your query requires a connection:

```
$mailquery = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_bides ON tbl_users.email = tbl_bides.bidder_id", $connection);
```

while replacing `$connection` with the variable you may be using to connect with, if that is `mysql_` to start with and that is unknown.

Make sure you are successfully connected using `mysql_` (although you should move to `mysqli_` or PDO).

- Different MySQL APIs do NOT intermix, so make sure you are using the same one to connect with.
- Read: [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Plus, I've placed a comment under your question about how you are using this "dynamic" method, but failed to respond/updated your question.

You will need to use a `WHERE` clause, and using the table/column that you are querying.

I.e.: `WHERE table.column = '$email'`

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

Then consult:

- [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` in case your query may have failed.

---

If you get a notice about deprecation, then you will need to use either `mysqli_` or PDO, which you should be switching to, as those `mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP releases such as PHP 7.0

Remember to use the same MySQL API from connection to query.

---

Change:

```
mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

to: (and using a conditional statement)

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers)){
  echo "Mail was sent and has done its job.";
}

else{
  echo "Error, check your logs.";
}
```

If you see `Mail was sent and has done its job.`, then `mail()` has done just that, its job.

Comment: It's Christmas Eve and I have to go now. I'll be back tomorrow to check on what's going on, or not going on.

Comment: Thank you Very Much... Now its working. I have not entered the right select statement. It has to be  $mailquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_bides ON tbl_users.users_id = tbl_bides.bidder_id WHERE bidder_id = $playerid", $con) or die(mysql_error()); Thanks again :)

Comment: @Andrew Thanks and Merry Christmas to you and plenty of Joy and Happiness also, cheers! You're welcome. I'm glad to hear that it was resolved. I had made an edit to the effect of adding a `WHERE` clause and that was the clincher. All the best Andrew!